# What are the connection managers to connect to an external SSAS cube in SSDT 2012

Tags: ssas, sql-server-data-tools, oledbconnection

We are experiencing issues when executing an SSIS package from a SQL Server job.  However, when we execute the package locally, it is successful.  The package connects to an external SSAS cube using MDX.  I have attached the error message below.  The connection manager is OLE DB Provider for Analysis Services 11.0.  We can successfully ping the external site where the cube is located from the server 
with the job.

[image]

Comment: We are using Windows Server 2008 R2 Core.  We are trying to access an external cube through HTTPS by sending a username/password in the connection string.  This is sent through an OLE DB connection in SSIS.  I found an article which says that "Because there is no Web browser, you cannot activate a Server Core installation or access the Internet through a firewall that requires users to log on."  Does anyone have any additional details on this...is this a futile effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this point, it appears that the issue is related to the windows server core install.  I found this link which outlines the issues related to core - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee441257(v=ws.10).aspx.  We can get the job to execute from a Windows Server with a full version install, but not on the core install.